# Is there any way of specifying a different author name on Google Code with git-svn?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, git-svn, google-code

My Gmail/Google username is not a username I generally go by, and one I'd rather forget. I don't seem to be able to change my Google username, but I contribute to a Google Code project using git svn.

In Git, I can specify my name and e-mail address using my ~/.gitconfig file in the [user] section. Same with Mercurial and hgrc.

But the moment I push it up to Google, my name becomes my (rather arbitrary) Google username and my e-mail address becomes that followed by a long hash. Is there any way of telling Google Code and svn or git-svn to let me use my real name rather than my (arbitrary) Google username in the svn repostiory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the displayed address after the fact by manipulating the svn:author property on the revision (using "svn propset"). I don't know enough about git-svn to know if it has a way to set the author itself.

Or you can convince the project in question to switch to Mercurial ;-). (update: or Git)

Comment: The second suggestion seems weird, why would someone using Git try to get the project to switch to Mercurial? And I don't think any svn-specific command will work since Git-svn is independent of svn itself.

Comment: You'd switch to Mercurial because git vs hg is a smaller impedance mismatch than git vs svn. And because Mercurial lets you set the author string to whatever you want when you commit. As for the second question, you run the svn propset command with the full url of the remote repository. git-svn won't come into the picture.

Comment: I'm trying to convince them to use Git, impedance mismatch be damned! I've tried svn propset and it didn't work on Google Code.

Comment: I just tested on one of my projects, and it worked. The one caveat is that only the project owner can do this. The sample command line is: svn propset svn:author --revprop -r 1234 somename https://somerepo.googlecode.com/svn

Comment: @mathepic because Google Code (still) can't support git directly, so at least hg is better than svn (one might say)